# how to read an ORC file in scala without hadoop ecosystem

Tags: scala, orc

I have snappy.orc formatted data in a S3 bucket that i need to read into a scala application.
I don't use non of the hadoop ecosystem components.

is there any way to read the file into the app without using hadoop?

I am using windows 10, JDK 1.8, scala-version 2.12.8

Comment: Have you tried this https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html ?

Comment: hi @HimanshuChaudhary , i tried but i still need to use an hadoop configuration for the reader. the readerOptions need an org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration argument.

if i use the regular implementation:
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Reader reader = OrcFile.createReader(new Path("./dataFile3.orc"),
                OrcFile.readerOptions(conf));

        RecordReader rows = reader.rows();
        VectorizedRowBatch batch = reader.getSchema().createRowBatch();

Comment: i get this Warnings:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: that looks more like log4j config issue. try configuring log4j.properties and log4j.xml as recommended in the link you posted above